# Do you think we should have a app-design tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just looking through the tags right now and found **website-design**, **web-applications** but was surprised to find out we had no **app-design** tag.

I am thinking of designing an Android app in the near future and this is how I ended up looking for it..do you think we will need it and will also encourage app designing questions or is it not that common on Graphic Design and probably won't be in the near future?

Comment: You can make tags as long as you have more than [300 points of reputation](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). There's nothing wrong in inventing new tags that seem appropriate.

Comment: @joojaa , well, that's what I was asking, if you guys think it could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not!

We do have these two, though:

[image]

I remember using interface-design for app-related questions. I see no harm in having a broader definition (interface) along with a more specific one (web-applications, app-design).

However, now that I look at it, I would consider merging interface-design and interface!

Comment: YISELA!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to ask for permission to make a tag. The admins will deal with random tags. So if you feel its OK just make it. I have nothing against such a tag.

Although for me it sounds more of a UX thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly broad tag but I can imagine use cases for it. However, don't make the tag unless it fits the question and no other tags describe that aspect of the question though!

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, go for it. I don't think it can do any harm right now.

I'd just like to add that tags are far more effective at bringing in traffic when they have a wiki and a description.

Anyone can submit or edit a wiki and description for peer review so if you'd like to encourage it that's the best thing you can do personally.